# Unable to declare data block for aws_iam_instance_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

Using terraform, I am trying to configure an ec2 instance using the same IAM profile as an already existing ec2 instance

I have tried adding tags to the existing IAM profile to be able to retrieve its info using a data block (declaration and data retrieving are not in the same VCS repository)

This is the resource declaration in a repository that we're going to name `core` and `var.app` has the value `core`

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion" {
  name = "instanceprofile-bastion-vpc-global-${var.app}-${var.env}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.bastion.name}"

  tags = {
    Name = "instanceprofile-bastion-vpc-global-${var.app}-${var.env}"
  }
}
```

And here is the data declaration in a repository that we're going to name `isc` (do note that we are using this form to retrieve other data from `core` to `isc` flawlessly for other things)

```
data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:name"
    values = ["instanceprofile-bastion-vpc-global-core-${var.env}"]
  }
}
```

When I'm using `terraform validate` or `terraform plan`, I am met with the following error messages

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on variables.dev.tf line 84, in data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion":
│   84: data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion" {
│ 
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on variables.dev.tf line 85, in data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion":
│   85:   filter {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "filter" are not expected here.
```

Three things may be the cause here:

- the changes for adding the tag to the `core` repository are not deployed yet, and terraform cannot find the data that I'm trying to retrieve from `isc`
- the declaration of a data block for `aws_iam_instance_profile` can't be filtered that way as shown in this [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_instance_profile)
- I can't assign an already used IAM instance profile to another ec2 instance

I have tried using the syntax from the doc in my second case, and I have no error message, but I am not sure at all if the correct data is obtained using this syntax, so I did not commit yet

```
data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion" {
  name = "instanceprofile-bastion-vpc-global-core-${var.env}"
}
```

Which ones of the aforementioned causes is happening?

Comment: The documentation you link shows that filter is not a block expected, so I'm not sure why you thought it was. The data sources using the name should have all the information that data source lists including parameters from Argument Reference and Attributes Reference. The error is clear, and you seem to have the solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the data `"aws_iam_instance_profile"` you need a [required name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_instance_profile#name)

```
data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion" {
  name = "instanceprofile-bastion-vpc-global-core-${var.env}"
}
```

You can use more than one EC2 instance with the same instance profile, but in this case you are indicating the concrete instance profile (yes, previously in `core` tf state) so you dont need to filter it.